# Sort Dictionary by Numerical Key

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, dictionary

I have a dictionary with integer keys and integer items, and just need to sort the dictionary based on the key, but all examples I've found work only for string keys.

Comment: "Sorting a dictionary" in some ways doesn't make sense. Dictionaries have no intrinsic order and there is no way to give them an order. Now, you could do something like take the *values* of the dictionary and put them in a sorted array. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly, I want to use the keys as x-values and items as y-values in a bar graph. Currently, I'm pulling the dictionary items and keys into arrays and can't independently sort or else I'll loose the relationship

Comment: VBA Array, the way the code is set to plot the graph however is in two separate arrays. Is there a good way for me to pull the dictionary key and items into a two dimensional array and then split the 2d array into 2 individual arrays -- one with keys and one with items, in the corresponding order?

Comment: It is easy enough to take a 2-dimensional array and split it into 2 - columns, but the only way I know how is the relatively crude way of via row by row looping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edited to add a solution to output X and Y arrays

you could use `SortedList` object and build a helper sub like follows:

```
Sub SortDictionary(dict As Object)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim key As Variant

    With CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
        For Each key In dict
            .Add key, dict(key)
        Next
        dict.RemoveAll
        For i = 0 To .Keys.Count - 1
            dict.Add .GetKey(i), .Item(.GetKey(i))
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

to be exploited as follows:

```
SortDictionary dict '<--| give 'SortDictionary()' sub a dictionary object to sort by its keys
```

for instance here's a test:

```
Sub main()

    Dim dict As Object
    Dim key As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With dict
        .Add 5, 15
        .Add 4, 14
        .Add 3, 13
        .Add 2, 12
        .Add 1, 11
    End With

    SortDictionary dict

    With dict
        For Each key In .Keys
            Debug.Print key, .Item(key)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

what above can be easily twicked to return `X` and `Y` arrays out of dictionary `keys` and `items`, as follows:

```
Sub SortDictionaryToArray(dict As Object, XArray As Variant, YArray As Variant)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim key As Variant

    With CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
        For Each key In dict
            .Add key, dict(key)
        Next
        ReDim XArray(0 To .Count)
        ReDim YArray(0 To .Count)
        For i = 0 To .Keys.Count - 1
            XArray(i) = .GetKey(i)
            YArray(i) = .Item(.GetKey(i))
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

to be exploited in your main sub as follows:

```
SortDictionaryToArray dict, Xs, Ys
```

as you can see in this complete test:

```
Sub main()

    Dim dict As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Xs As Variant, Ys As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With dict
        .Add 5, 15
        .Add 4, 14
        .Add 3, 13
        .Add 2, 12
        .Add 1, 11
    End With

    SortDictionaryToArray dict, Xs, Ys

    For i = 0 To UBound(Xs)
        Debug.Print Xs(i), Ys(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 9):

Grab the keys as an array, sort that array, then use the sorted array to pull the values from the dictionary.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim d As Object
    Dim i As Long, arr, k

    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")


    With d
        .Add 3, 33
        .Add 1, 33
        .Add 2, 55
        .Add 5, 77
    End With

    arr = d.keys  '<< get keys in an array

    ' "sort" through the array, and get the values from the dictionary
    Debug.Print "key", "value"
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        k = Application.Small(arr, i + 1)
        Debug.Print k, d(k)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Output:

```
  key          value
  1             33   
  2             55   
  3             33   
  5             77
```

Comment: I like the idea of using 'Application.Small' and a simple array for sorting.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution based on using the .Net container [ArrayList](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Arraylist_en.html) -- which can be used in VBA. It takes much of the hassle out of sorting:

```
Function DictToSortedArray(D As Object) As Variant
    'returns a 1-based 2-dimensional sorted array
    'sorted by the keys
    Dim A As Variant, i As Long, AL As Object, k As Variant

    Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    For Each k In D
        AL.Add k
    Next k

    AL.Sort

    ReDim A(1 To AL.Count, 1 To 2)

    For i = 1 To AL.Count
        A(i, 1) = AL(i - 1)
        A(i, 2) = D(AL(i - 1))
    Next i

    DictToSortedArray = A
End Function
```

A simple test:

```
Sub test()
    Dim D As Object
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    D.Add 5, 8
    D.Add 3, 7
    D.Add 42, 9
    D.Add 1, 7
    D.Add 10, 11

    A = DictToSortedArray(D)
    For i = 1 To 5
        Debug.Print A(i, 1) & ", " & A(i, 2)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Output:

```
1, 7
3, 7
5, 8
10, 11
42, 9
```

Answer (score 1):

- get the keys and items into a dictionary, overwriting the items to maintain unique keys
- copy the keys to a 1-D array
- sort the 1-D array
- reuse one of the temporary variants as a 2-D array
- put the sorted 'keys' into the 2-D array and use the 'keys' to call the associated item from the original dictionary to the second rank.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub sortedDictionary()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, d As Long, dict As Object
    Dim vKEYs As Variant, tmp As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        For d = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            dict.Item(.Cells(d, "A").Value2) = .Cells(d, "B").Value2
        Next d

        vKEYs = dict.keys

        For i = LBound(vKEYs) + 1 To UBound(vKEYs)
            For j = LBound(vKEYs) To UBound(vKEYs) - 1
                If vKEYs(j) > vKEYs(i) Then
                    tmp = vKEYs(j)
                    vKEYs(j) = vKEYs(i)
                    vKEYs(i) = tmp
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        ReDim tmp(1 To UBound(vKEYs) + 1, 1 To 2)

        For i = LBound(vKEYs) To UBound(vKEYs)
            tmp(i + 1, 1) = vKEYs(i)
            tmp(i + 1, 2) = dict.Item(vKEYs(i))
        Next i

        .Cells(2, "E").Resize(UBound(tmp, 1), UBound(tmp, 2)) = tmp
    End With
End Sub
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: @JohnColeman - This was really just an intellectual exercise. Putting the sorted 2-D array back into the worksheet was for demonstration purposes although I suppose I could have screenshot the watch window.